# Error en Python con una función de latitud y longitud

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataset, visualización-de-datos

Espero que estén todos bien con todo el tema del Coronavirus. He aprovechado el confinamiento para retomar un práctico que tenía pendiente en mis estudios.

Estoy haciendo una búsqueda con la latitud y longitud de diversos barrios de Manhattan y luego usando el foursquare para obtener datos sobre locales comerciales.

El problema es que teniendo este DF:

> ```
>     Borough                District    latitude    longitude
> 0  Manhattan CB 1 Battery Park City   40.711017   -74.016937
> 1  Manhattan CB 1 Financial District  40.707612   -74.009378
> 2  Manhattan CB 1 Tribeca             40.715380   -74.009306
> 3  Manhattan CB 2 Chinatown           40.716491   -73.996250
> 4  Manhattan CB 2 Greenwich Village   40.731980   -73.996566
> 5  Manhattan CB 2 Little Italy        40.719273   -73.998215
> 6  Manhattan CB 2 Lower East Side     40.715936   -73.986806
> 7  Manhattan CB 2 NoHo                40.725875   -73.993957
> 8  Manhattan CB 2 SoHo                40.722880   -73.998750
> 9  Manhattan CB 2 West Village        40.734186   -74.005580
> 10 Manhattan CB 3 Alphabet City   40.725102   -73.979583
> 11 Manhattan CB 3 Chinatown       40.716491   -73.996250
> 12 Manhattan CB 3 East Village    40.729269   -73.987361
> 13 Manhattan CB 3 Lower East Side 40.715936   -73.986806
> 14 Manhattan CB 3 Two Bridges     40.711288   -73.992233
> 15 Manhattan CB 4 Chelsea         40.746491   -74.001528
> 19 Manhattan CB 5 Midtown         40.762268   -73.979544
> 20 Manhattan CB 6 Gramercy Park   40.737925   -73.985932
> 21 Manhattan CB 6 Kips Bay        40.739546   -73.977083
> 22 Manhattan CB 6 Rose Hill       40.743338   -73.984159
> 23 Manhattan CB 6 Murray Hill     40.760000   -73.813056
> 24 Manhattan CB 6 Peter Cooper Village    40.733960   -73.977423
> 25 Manhattan CB 6 Stuyvesant Town 40.731971   -73.978093
> 26 Manhattan CB 6 Sutton Place    41.114852   -72.371285
> 27 Manhattan CB 6 Tudor City  40.748623   -73.971389
> 28 Manhattan CB 6 Turtle Bay  40.753467   -73.968866
> 29 Manhattan CB 6 Waterside Plaza 40.737581   -73.973242
> 30 Manhattan CB 7 Lincoln Square  40.772319   -73.984401
> 31 Manhattan CB 7 Manhattan Valley    40.799776   -73.967772
> 32 Manhattan CB 7 Upper West Side 40.787045   -73.975416
> 33 Manhattan CB 8 Lenox Hill  40.766437   -73.959017
> 34 Manhattan CB 8 Roosevelt Island    40.761418   -73.950228
> 35 Manhattan CB 8 Upper East Side 40.773702   -73.964120
> 36 Manhattan CB 8 Yorkville   40.778007   -73.948202
> 37 Manhattan CB 9 Hamilton Heights    40.824145   -73.950062
> 38 Manhattan CB 9 Manhattanville  40.815778   -73.951554
> 39 Manhattan CB 9 Morningside Heights 40.810000   -73.962500
> 40 Manhattan CB 10    Harlem  40.807879   -73.945415
> 41 Manhattan CB 10    Polo Grounds    41.101948   -72.373218
> 42 Manhattan CB 11    East Harlem 40.794722   -73.942500
> 43 Manhattan CB 11    Randall's Island    40.796768   -73.922082
> 45 Manhattan CB 11    Wards Island    40.787601   -73.925415
> 46 Manhattan CB 12    Inwood  40.869258   -73.920495
> 47    Manhattan CB 12 Washington Heights  40.840198   -73.940221
> ```

Al pasarlo por la siguiente iteración:

```
    for i in np.arange(0, NY.shape[0]):

    # We choose to search by category with a 500m radius.
    radius = 600
    LIMIT = 200
    category_id = '4bf58dd8d48988d102951735' #ID for Accessory stores

    latitude = NY['latitude'][i]
    longitude = NY['longitude'][i]
  # Define the corresponding URL
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&categoryId={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, VERSION, category_id, radius, LIMIT)

    # Send the GET Request
    results = requests.get(url).json()

    # Get relevant part of JSON and transform it into a pandas dataframe
    # assign relevant part of JSON to venues
    venues = results['response']['venues']

    # tranform venues into a dataframe
    dataframe = json_normalize(venues)
    dataframe.head()

# keep only columns that include venue name, and anything that is associated with location
    filtered_columns = ['name', 'categories'] + [col for col in dataframe.columns if col.startswith('location.')] + ['id']
    dataframe_filtered = dataframe.loc[:, filtered_columns]


    # function that extracts the category of the venue
    def get_category_type(row):
        try:
            categories_list = row['categories']
        except:
            categories_list = row['venue.categories']

        if len(categories_list) == 0:
            return None

        else:
            return categories_list[0]['name']

    # filter the category for each row
    dataframe_filtered['categories'] = dataframe_filtered.apply(get_category_type, axis=1)

    # clean column names by keeping only last term
    dataframe_filtered.columns = [column.split('.')[-1] for column in dataframe_filtered.columns]

    print(str(i) + ') The number of shops in ' +NY['District'][i] + ' is ' +str(dataframe_filtered.shape[0]) + '\n')
    N_shop.append(dataframe_filtered.shape[0])
```

Ocurre que va bien, hasta que llega a la fila nº16, donde da este error:

> ```
> 10) The number of shops in Alphabet City is 7
>
> 11) The number of shops in  Chinatown is 39
>
> 12) The number of shops in  East Village is 20
>
> 13) The number of shops in  Lower East Side is 18
>
> 14) The number of shops in  Two Bridges is 3
>
> 15) The number of shops in Chelsea is 14
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-24-5b54770e4fe0> in <module>
>       6     category_id = '4bf58dd8d48988d102951735' #ID for Accessory stores
>       7 
> ----> 8     latitude = NY['latitude'][i]
>       9     longitude = NY['longitude'][i]
>      10   # Define the corresponding URL
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
>     866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
>     867         try:
> --> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
>     869 
>     870             if not is_scalar(result):
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
>    4372         try:
>    4373             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
> -> 4374                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
>    4375         except KeyError as e1:
>    4376             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 16
> ```

He probado diversas opciones pero sin exito, no logro darme cuenta donde esta el error. Si alguien puede iluminarme, se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iteras sobre el DataFrame usando un `for` y un rango generado con `np.arange` que usas para indizar sobre el DataFrame. El problema es que asumes que los índices del DataFrame van desde 0 hasta len(DataFrame), lo cual no es cierto.

Los índices del DataFrame van del 0 al 47 pero faltan los índices 16, 17, 18 y 44. `np.arange` por su parte genera los índices del 0 al 43 sin saltarse ninguno...

Cuando intentas indizar sobre la fila con índice 16 tienes un `KeyError` porque el índice 16 no existe en el Dataframe...

Podrías resetear el índice si no es importante mantenerlo, pero mejor tienes mejores opciones. Una muy simple sin modficar nada tu código es hacer:

```
for i in NY.index:
    # Resto igual
```

Yo para estos casos en los que no es posible vectorizar, solo usas algunas columnas y el DataFrame no es excesivamente grande, prefiero usar directamente `zip` sobre las columnas que necesitamos:

```
for latitude, longitude, district in zip(NY['latitude'], NY['longitude'], NY['District']):
    # usa directamente las variables latitude, longitude y district donde las necesites
```

  -

Comment: Muchas gracias! Aún no lo he probado. Pero tiene mucho sentido. Intuía que el error provenía por la falta de los índices 16, 18... Pero no tenia claro como resolverlo. Hoy mismo al.llegar del trabajo lo pruebo! Saludos